# How to get the ports that are in "ESTABLISHED" state in C#

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, udp, port

I am new to the .NET framework.

Currently working on a program that checks if the port is ready to use.
I have used `IPGlobalProperties` to get the port info which was specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3063203/10650269)

```
IPGlobalProperties ipGP = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
IPEndPoint[] tcpEndPoints= ipGP.GetActiveTcpListeners();
IPEndPoint[] updEndPoints = ipGP.GetActiveUdpListeners();
// port validation
```

Since "ESTABLISHED" & "LISTENING" states refer to open ports
as per this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854354/difference-between-established-and-listening)

I also need a solution to get the port that is in the "ESTABLISHED" state.
Is there a way to get the ports that are in the "ESTABLISHED" state in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you want to see exactly, but this will show you all the active local established sockets and ports

```
     var active = result.GetActiveTcpConnections().Where(c => c.State == TcpState.Established);
     active.Select(c => $"{c.LocalEndPoint.Address} {c.LocalEndPoint.Port}")
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```